# Get values for all rows in left join

Tags: mysql, sql, apache-spark-sql

I have 3 tables. The first table is the main table, the second table I left join it with the main table and the third table I left join it with the second table. So here's how it looks:

```
Main Table
Order  Item  Supplier
1      1      X
1      2      X

Second Table
Order  LineNumber
1      22

Third Table
LineNumber  Name
22          F
```

After doing the joins, I get:

```
Order  Item  Supplier  Name
1      1     X         F
1      2     X         null
```

Here's what I want:

```
Order  Item  Supplier  Name
1      1     X         F
1      2     X         F
```

How can I achieve this? Here's my code:

```
select *, third.Name from main left join second on main.order = second.order left join third on second.LineNumber = third.LineNumber
```

Sometimes the main table will include orders that are not in the second table, that's why I have a left join. Same thing with the third table and second

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
select main.Order,Item,Supplier,Name from main 
left join second on main.Order = second.Order  
left join third on second.LineNumber = third.LineNumber
```

Comment: Isn't this the same thin as what I'm doing?

Comment: Question query is invalid . remove 'and' before the left join

Comment: Yes that's what I meant. This query won't work

Comment: check answer query .. otherwise add correct sample data and expect result

Comment: I did in my question

Comment: below query return what you are expected . otherwise correct your sample data